# Laravel Guzzle error -- cURL error 7: Failed connect to api.github.com:80; Connection timed out

Tags: curl, laravel-4, github-api, guzzle

I am Trying to get github users details with http request in laravel.

I am using package Guzzle for this.
My controller like below,

```
 public function apiProject()
 {
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->get('http://api.github.com/users/jishadp369');
    dd($response->getBody());
 }
```

When i point the route in browser, the browser loading some time and throwing error like

```
cURL error 7: Failed connect to api.github.com:80; Connection timed out
```

I am tried in terminal with curl i can getting result finely.

In Firebug->Net : it showing 500 Internal server error,

How can i solve this issue. ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->get('http://guzzlephp.org');
    $res = $client->get('https://api.github.com/users/jishadp369');
    echo $res->getStatusCode();
    // "200"
    echo $res->getHeader('content-type');
    // 'application/json; charset=utf8'
    echo $res->getBody();
    // {"type":"User"...'
    var_export($res->json());
```

// Outputs the JSON decoded data